# useFocusEffect doesn't update setstate

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to use useFocusEffect to setState.
but I can't update state...

How can i fix this?

```
const [isFocuse, setIsFocuse] = useState(true);

  useFocusEffect(
      React.useCallback(() => {
        setIsFocuse('sample1');
        console.log('mount', isFocuse); // mount true
        return () => {
          setIsFocuse('sample2');
          console.log('unmount', isFocuse); // unmount true
        };
      }, []),
  );
```

Comment: Where are you using isFocuse? nothing wrong with the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know its a old question but for anyone looking for solution.
According to React navigation docs on [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/).
You need to add state you need to change as a dependency to your useCallback hook.
So correct code will be.
`

> ```
>    const [isFocuse, setIsFocuse] = useState(true);
>        useFocusEffect(
>            React.useCallback(() => {
>                setIsFocuse('sample1');
>                console.log('mount', isFocuse); 
>                return () => {
>                    setIsFocuse('sample2');
>                    console.log('unmount', isFocuse); 
>                };
>   }, [isFocuse]));`
> ```

And that will work.

PS- setState or its hooks equivalent is async task so console.log() may run before state is updated will result is incorrect values of log in this case. You can use useEffect hook as with isFocuse as dependency to log the change in state

Comment: When I update the state in the useCallback function, and have have the current state as a dependency the application freezes. Any idea?

Comment: @RayKay91 Though it has nothing to do with the original post. I don't see why the app would freeze, my best guess would be that the state which is the dependency is being altered in the callback function causing it to be called in a loop. Could you share your code?

Comment: I managed to sort it. The state was being updated in the callback. I removed any dependencies from the callback and just updated the state by passing in a function to setState. It seems to work.